# Object created on a remote server returns no output

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

This code runs perfectly fine locally:

```
$objAutoUpdate = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate"
 $objautoupdate.settings
```

This however does NOT return anything:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName qaildc01 -ScriptBlock { 

 $objAutoUpdate = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate"
 $objautoupdate.settings

 }
```

Actually even when using Enter-Pssession running the above object command does not return anything.

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting a result for a reason, but you're not getting that reason returned back to you.

Lets debug it :)

So, first.. try to create the object on the remote machine and get all the properties of the object back

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName MACHINENAME-HERE -ScriptBlock {
    $PSAUObject = (New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate")
    $PSAUObject | Select *
}
```

you should get something like that:

```
Settings       : 
ServiceEnabled : 
Results        : System.__ComObject
PSComputerName : MACHINENAME
RunspaceId     : 3a951a05-9856-4ad2-8978-1b5827c42e32
```

now, you will probably get in return all the available properties of the object, Settings seems to be empty but you will be able to access the Results property
try the following:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName MACHINENAME-HERE -ScriptBlock {
    $PSAUObject = (New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate")
    $PSAUObject | Select -ExpandProperty "Results"
    $PSAUObject | Select -ExpandProperty "Settings"
}
```

While trying to retrieve the Settings property, i received an exception, probably due to UAC

```
Exception getting "Settings": "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (System.__ComObject:PSObject) [Select-Object], GetValueInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyEvaluationExpand,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand
```

Good luck :)

Comment: That's a good direction. Although it's not UAC. I'll give you the vote up for progression but I'm afraid it's not a full answer yet.